# Javascript Fancybox 2 close button/link event not working

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, fancybox

Im creating a terms and conditions popup using Fancybox 2 that shows when a user logs into our wordpress site, this content is retrieved from a div tag and uses php to find the correct content from wordpress pages.  They need to click on an accept button to move on and close the popup, this link is generated within the div tag.  Using a seperate php file, their user id is added to a table which shows they have accepted the ts and cs.  Everything works except the accept button.  When I click the Accept link the window does not fully close, it stays on screen, yet the onclose event is triggered as my table is updated with the users id.  I can see the window flash in and out quickly when I click anywhere on the content including the link.  So I am guessing there is some sort of invisible overlay ontop of the fancybox preventing the link from being executed?

Here is my code

```
<a class="fancybox" href="test" style="display:none;">ddd</a>
        <div id="test" style="display:none;height:600;width:750px;">
                        <?php
        global $blog_id,$wpdb;
        // query the DB to retrieve the post 'termsofservice' from the localized sites posts table
        $tnc_notification = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "select post_content from wp_posts where post_title='Terms & Conditions' and post_status='publish';" ) );
            echo "<p>TERMS and CONDITIONS have changed, please read the new terms and conditions.  By closing this window you automatically accept them</p>";

                    echo '<a href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close();">Accept </a> ';

                    echo "<p>".$tnc_notification."</p>";
        ?>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function callTNC(){
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    jQuery("#test").fancybox({
                                                'closeBtn': false,
                                                'closeClick': false,
                                                'modal': true,
                                                'maxHeight': 600,
                                                'maxWidth': 750,
                                                afterClose : function (){
                                                    //add the user into the tnc accepted table
                                                    $.get("http://mysite.com/tncaccept.php");
                                                }
                    }).trigger('click');

            });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT SOLUTION FOUND:
OK, I managed to fix this.  You have to create a reference in the link and have the actual close function within the 
jQuery(document).ready(function() declaration
So what was happening is the javascript in the accept link/button was not properly calling fancybox close.

So first create the reference in the accept link/button

```
echo '<a href="#" id="closeFancy">Accept</a> ';
```

and then create the function within the fancybox declaration/initialization:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function callTNC(){
            jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
                                            jQuery("#closeFancy").click(function(){
                                                jQuery.fancybox.close();
                                                return false;
                                            });
                    jQuery("#test").fancybox({
                                                'closeBtn': false,
                                                'closeClick': false,
                                                'modal': true,
                                                'maxHeight': 600,
                                                'maxWidth': 750,
                                                helpers   : { 
                                                    overlay : {closeClick: false} // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox 
                                                },

                                                afterClose : function (){
                                                    //add the user into the tnc accepted table
                                                    $.get("http://mysite.com/tncaccept.php");
                                                }
                    }).trigger('click');
                                            //$("#acceptClose").click(function(){
                                            //    $.fancybox.close();
                                            //    return false;
                                            //});
            });
}
```